# Parse Eigen Matrix with Boost Spirit X3

Tags: c++, matrix, boost, eigen, boost-spirit-x3

I'm trying to parse an `Eigen::Matrix3f` matrix with Boost Spirit X3, where the input string is `matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty)` and the resulting Eigen 3x3 matrix will be the following:

```
[a, c, tx
 b, d, ty
 0, 0, 1]
```

I can already synthesize `std::vector<float>` attributes, but I would like to synthesize `Eigen::Matrix3f` instead. What would be the best way to synthesize an `Eigen::Matrix3f` (or any other custom matrix type for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `Semantic Actions`, here's the code:

```
auto identity = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx) = Eigen::Matrix3f::Identity();};
auto a = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(0,0) = x3::_attr(ctx);};
auto b = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(1,0) = x3::_attr(ctx);};
auto c = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(0,1) = x3::_attr(ctx);};
auto d = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(1,1) = x3::_attr(ctx);};
auto tx = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(0,2) = x3::_attr(ctx);};
auto ty = [&](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)(1,2) = x3::_attr(ctx);};

auto matRule = x3::rule<class MatId, Eigen::Matrix3f>() = x3::eps[identity] >> x3::no_case["matrix"]
                                                                                >> "("
                                                                                >> x3::float_[a]
                                                                                >> ","
                                                                                >> x3::float_[b]
                                                                                >> ","
                                                                                >> x3::float_[c]
                                                                                >> ","
                                                                                >> x3::float_[d]
                                                                                >> ","
                                                                                >> x3::float_[tx]
                                                                                >> ","
                                                                                >> x3::float_[ty]
                                                                                >> ")";

std::string teststr = "matrix(2,3,4,5,6,7)";
Eigen::Matrix3f mat;
bool success = x3::phrase_parse(teststr.begin(), teststr.end(), matRule, x3::space, mat);

if (success) std::cout << mat << std::endl;
```